# How do I know it's a valid gdi region handle?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, gdi, winapi

or other gdi handle, such as pen brush. how do i know is it valid?

Comment: Why do you need this? Since you are the one who creates and destroys the GDI objects, you should be knowing whether they are valid or not.

Comment: i just create it, i don't know if it successed.

Comment: Most GDI functions will return a `NULL` handle if they fail. Just check the MSDN documentation for the specific functions you are interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *never* get yourself into a situation where you might be holding onto a handle that isn't valid.  If necessary, set the handle to NULL after calling DeleteObject() so it is completely obvious.  Assuming that a GDI function will give you a FALSE return value because you passed a bad handle isn't safe.

Comment: +1. In general this is the case, however reading his modifying comment he wants to check whether a GDI creation function succeeded. Failed creates return NULL. Why NULL? GDI handles used to be pointers They're not anymore.

Comment: Okay, it that case call your custom CrashAndBurnMyAppBecauseIHaveANastyHandleLeakInMyProgram() function.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: where did you get the handle from?

Simply speaking, it's like with the art: how do you know it's authentic, not a fake?
There're some "heuristics", but the only 100%-working way is to know where is it from.

So, regarding the GDI regions: you should only trust those region handles that are returned by GDI functions.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try `GetObject()` or `GetObjectType()`. They should return NULL if the object handle is invalid.

I can see where you'd want to use this for debugging. In a perfect world, we keep track of our objects and know where they are at all times.

Ours is not a perfect world.